# swipeRevealLayout's working

Tags: android, listview

I am a beginner in Android and I cant understand how to use swipeRevealLayout to create swipe left and right on listview items? can anyone please share a demo code of the application employing this.

Comment: There are many libraries available. Just dig a google properly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

These are good tutorial check this

[1 Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2017/02/android-creating-gmail-like-inbox-using-recyclerview/)

[2 Tutorial](https://www.spaceotechnologies.com/swipe-delete-listview-android-example/)

Hope this will help you